# Animating SVG group object - transform rotate with styled-components doesnt rotate around circle origin

Tags: reactjs, svg, redux, styled-components

I have an SVG circle and some line objects making a simple crosshair mouse cursor that i'm trying to animate with styled-components. When the cursor hovers over certain objects I'd like the line elements within the cursor to rotate around the origin of the circle element which makes up the cursor. A redux useSelector hook gives access to the mouseover/mouseout state of the components being hovered over. This part works well, as a simple stroke color change can be elicited using this method

```
const Cursor = (props) => {

const hoverState = useSelector(state => state.gameState.targetHovered);

// ... 
return (
        <Crosshair isHovering={hoverState} position={props.position}>
                <circle 
                    cx={cursorCoordinates.cx}
                    cy={cursorCoordinates.cy}
                    r={cursorCoordinates.outerRadius}
                    style={cursorStyle} 
                />
                <circle 
                    cx={cursorCoordinates.cx}
                    cy={cursorCoordinates.cy}
                    r={cursorCoordinates.innerRadius}
                    style={cursorStyle} 
                />

                <line 
                    id="top"
                    x1={cursorCoordinates.cx - cursorCoordinates.outerRadius} 
                    y1={cursorCoordinates.cy}
                    x2={cursorCoordinates.cx - cursorCoordinates.innerRadius}
                    y2={cursorCoordinates.cy}
                    style={crossHairStyle}
                />
                <line 
                    id="bottom"
                    x1={cursorCoordinates.cx + cursorCoordinates.innerRadius} 
                    y1={cursorCoordinates.cy}
                    x2={cursorCoordinates.cx + cursorCoordinates.outerRadius}
                    y2={cursorCoordinates.cy}
                    style={crossHairStyle}
                />
        </Crosshair>
    );
```

and the code for the styled components...

```
const lockOn = (x, y) => keyframes`
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    100% { 
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
`;

const Crosshair = styled.g`
    transform-origin: ${props => props.position.x} ${props => props.position.y};
    animation: ${props => props.isHovering ? lockOn : 'none'} 1s linear;
`;
```

i've tried to express the keyframes in a number of different ways, but each time, instead of rotating the elements within the styled group component, when a target object is hovered over by the cursor the animation instead flings it off to the right, as if the transform origin is incorrect somehow. Removing the transform-origin from Crosshair exhibits the same behaviour

I'm sure i'm making a simple syntax error. Any ideas?

Comment: presumably you need transform-box: fill-box; If that doesn't work please provide a [mcve] i.e. something we can directly run ourselves.

Comment: @RobertLongson yep, that was the solution. Just 2 lines of code inside the styled.g (see below)

Answer (score 0):

Solution, as pointed out by @RobertLongson in the comments was to add

```
transform-box: fill-box;
```

inside the styled.g component, otherwise the transform-origin is the centre of the SVG object. More details on the MDN docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box

Adding a transform-origin was also necessary. Note 'forwards' in the animation was required to prevent it from resetting while the cursor was still hovering over an object

```
const lockOn = (x, y) => keyframes`
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    to { 
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
`;

const Crosshair = styled.g`
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    animation: ${props => props.isHovering ? lockOn : 'none'} 0.3s linear forwards;
`;
```